# How to read all Example records from a TFRecord file in one go using Dataset API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using a Spark job to generate a `TFRecord` file which will be my vocabulary file of (word, count) pairs.

I want to load the entire file at once using the Dataset API since my vocabulary file could be on HDFS and might be split across multiple physical files.  That said, I am finding it pretty unintuitive.  Here's my code so far:

```
def parse(example):
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(example, features={
        'token': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
        'count': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
    })
    return parsed['token'], parsed['count']

filenames = tf.gfile.Glob(filenames)
dataset   = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset   = dataset.map(parse)
dataset   = dataset.batch(MAX_VOCAB_FILE)
iterator  = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

token, token_count = iterator.get_next()
```

Using a huge, fixed up-front batch size is the only way I can think of slurping up all the data at once in a tensor of `shape=(num_entries,)`.  It seems to run pretty slow as well.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar at one point. It's not intuitive, but there's an answer buried in the TF docs for [Importing Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_values_from_an_iterator).

To make my solution easier to follow, I'll assume that your code is wrapped in a method called `get_batch`:

```
def get_batch(filenames, batch_size):
    # your code
    return token, token_count
```

where the `batch_size` argument replaces `MAX_VOCAB_FILE` in your example. If you want to print all successive `(token, token_count)` pairs to stdout, one line at a time, you'd do this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    example = get_batch(filenames, 1)
    while True:
        print(sess.run(example))
```

Then the iterator is exhausted, the loop exits with an `OutOfRangeError`. Each record emitted is a pair of tensors recast as numpy objects.

Hope this is enough detail to do something useful with.